# boot function is not firing up on model

Tags: laravel-5

```
class WalletHistory extends ABModel
{
    protected static function boot() {
        echo 'boot';exit;
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

For above code, I have written some code in boot function in model and it is not firing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the creating method should be called within boot():

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

 static::creating(function ($model) {
     $model->foo = 'bar';
 });
}
```

And The static boot() method is automatically run whenever a model is instantiated. So here boot method will be called before creating the model i.e. : `Model::create();` 
Hope it helps. For more information may need to see your code.